# Rails polymorphic naming edge cases

Tags: ruby-on-rails, polymorphism, naming-conventions, naming

I have a model called ImageGallery which can belong to many different models. Usually in rails you just suffix -able to the name to come up with the polymorphic name but here "image_galleryable" doesn't sound right.

How should a polymorphic association be named when suffixing -able doesn't work well?

Answer (score 2):

Nothing will break in rails if you do not follow the convention, see http://samuelmullen.com/articles/naming_conventions_for_polymorphic_associations/

> Naming things is really hard, and any programmer who’s been in the
>   trenches will tell you that. When you get it right, thinking about the
>   design and coding of the program just flows. When you get it wrong, an
>   added level of effort is required to translate the logic from what
>   it’s named to what it means.
>
> When dealing with ActiveRecord’s polymorphic relationships, follow the
>   conventions outlined above and it will take your closer toward naming
>   things well. When they don’t, ignore them; they’re only conventions.

I think I would have used a noun here, maybe just image

Comment: its best if you include the useful part of the link in your answer